# macmini wifi internet only works if lan cable unpluged

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, routing, mac-mini

I use macmini to compile mac version of my program, I use `ssh` and `vnc` from linux, but problem is that I can only get either internet via wifi(`en1`) or local connection via ethernet(`en0`).
if I do enable ethernet (`en0`) connection the internet is no longer working, although the wifi(`en1`) interface is still active. I suspect it is a routing problem.
I have been trying for hours using `route delete` and `route add 0.0.0.0 ...`, `netstat -na` etc, but since I lack some knowledge my attempts lack consistency.
I need both, lan for vnc and wifi for internet. VNC is slow over wifi and internet is required as well for some reasons.

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING>
        ether a8:20:66:36:21:ea
        inet6 fe80::aa20:66ff:fe36:21ea%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
        inet 192.168.1.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
        status: active
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 88:53:95:2a:a2:89
        inet6 fe80::8a53:95ff:fe2a:a289%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
        inet 192.168.88.140 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.88.255
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I shall try to guess at what the problem might be...   As I'm probably going to state incorrect assumptions, please correct me, and I'll try again with the new information.

I assume both interfaces are being configured via DHCP.  In that case, both your eth0 interface and your eth1 interface are receiving a 'gw' ip from their respective DHCP servers.  Since the eth0 interface does not have a route to the Internet (a valid gw), whenever it is enabled, your connection to the Internet is dropping.

To make your Wi-Fi interface take precedence over the LAN interface, go into System Preferences..Network, and look for the gear icon in the lower left.  Pull it down and select 'Set Service Order'.  A new window will pop up.  Drag Wi-Fi so that it's above Ethernet (or drag Ethernet so that it's below Wi-Fi), click <kbd>OK</kbd> to dismiss the service order window, then <kbd>Apply</kbd> in the main network window.  This ought to give Wi-Fi a preferred status over your Ethernet connection.